# multiple token/color highlighter in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As I'm a poweruser of **Notepad++ 'Style token'-feature** and [Context Highlight](http://www.basson.at/firefox-addons/contexthighlight) Firefox-addon but mainly working with Eclipse (currently 4.5.1), I tried to find an equivalent solution as eclipse-plugin.

At the marketplace I came across [Controlflow Code Search](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ctrlflow-code-search) and [Glance](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/glance), but both **did not meet** my requirements.

Question is: is there a eclipse plugin available, which allows me to

- highlight multiple tokens
- in different colors
- at the same time

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain what that Notepad++ feature actually does in layman's terms, or point to doc written about it?

Comment: added a picture with tokens 'lore','lorem','sed' highlighted in notepad++ with different styles.